# Can I have more than one executable file with JavaFX native building tool?

Tags: java, windows, gradle, javafx, javafx-gradle-plugin

I'm using the [JavaFX Gradle plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin) to build my JavaFX application. Is it possible to have more than one executable built with different main classes? If so, how?

Comment: When you say binary are you talking about and executable file?

Comment: Yes, I mean am executable file

Comment: Is this not a matter of just a right click copy?

Comment: Right click copy is not part of a build system.

Comment: This is probably out of my league.

Comment: @Pablo http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible, as the underlying `javapackager` does support this.

As I'm understanding you correct, you have a project, where you have multiple entry-points and now you want to create native launchers/binaries for each of that entry-point. This is called "secondary launcher" inside the gradle plugin and even inside the `javapackager`.

To create multiple executables with the same bundle, just add this inside your buildfile:

```
jfx {
    // ... normal configuration ...

    // your secondary entry points, each will create a native executable (and one .cfg-file for each)
    secondaryLaunchers = [
        // second executable
        [
            appName: 'somethingDifferent'
            // will create the same executable, just with a different name (so this is demo-purpose only)
        ],
        // third executable
        [
            appName: 'somethingDifferent2',
            // specify your different entry-point
            mainClass: 'your.different.entrypoint.MainApp'
            // other possible entries: "jfxMainAppJarName", "jvmProperties", "jvmArgs", "userJvmArgs", "nativeReleaseVersion", "needShortcut", "needMenu", "vendor", "identifier"
        ]
    ]
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I'm the creator of the JavaFX Gradle plugin ;)

Comment: Just a note: when you have any question, you might want to open an issue in the github-project or even get in direct contact via e-mail. This is often faster, but I can understand that SO is an excellent "research"-location ;)

Comment: Suggestion:- [Example](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin/blob/master/README.md#example-buildgradle) misses that ideal line of documentation in that case.

Comment: Thank you @FibreFoX. These types of answers are rare and it should be SO should strive for.