# Can I add more start menu items to my program with JavaFX?

Tags: java, windows, gradle, javafx, javafx-gradle-plugin

I'm using the [JavaFX Gradle plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin) to build my JavaFX application. Is it possible to add more than one start menu item to the finished installer?

Comment: I've checked this, it seems that some special configuration is needed. When I found something working, I will provide you with an answer. **Disclaimer:** I'm the creator of the JavaFX Gradle plugin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After answering your [other question regarding additional native launchers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46448239/can-i-have-more-than-one-executable-filewith-javafx-native-building-tool/) I checked the sources of the JDK, to see what is needed for this.

Any launcher with the enabled "needMenu"-property will be reflected in some menu-entry inside the start-menu. Just add something like this to your buildfile:

```
jfx {
    // ... normal configuration ...

    // your secondary entry points, each will inherit the configuration, unless you specify otherwise here
    secondaryLaunchers = [
        [
            appName: 'somethingDifferent2',
            mainClass: 'your.different.entrypoint.MainApp',
            // the following is required for an start-menu entry
            needMenu: true
        ]
    ]
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I'm the creator of that JavaFX-Gradle-plugin

Comment: That was easy. Thank you @FibreFox.